APS - AEC Data Model API - EMEA - cannot retrieve designs
Trying to migrate my Data Model API development from US to EMEA Hub.
In US Hub everything goes ok.
In EMEA Hub, I can get the HubId (with getHubs), the ProjectId (with GetProjects).
GetProject also works ok.
But cannot list project designs with GetDesignsByProject.
Returns an error indicating that no AEC data was found [404 Not Found]. see below.
The rvt files are the same in US and EMEA hub...
The indicated HubId matches the Hub that hosts the projectId passed. Seams that projectId was well passed and well understood.
Don't know how to debug this call with aecDesignExtractionStatus...
Any ideas?
        "message": "[404 Not Found] Requested resource not found. No AEC data found for the provided hub id b.xxxxxxx. This might be due to the absence of AEC data in the specified hub. If data extraction is currently underway, it may not have completed yet. Please consider querying 'aecDesignExtractionStatus' for extraction status and details.",
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 2,
                "column": 13
            }
        ],
        "path": [
            "aecDesignsByProject"
        ],
        "extensions": {
            "correlation_id": "xxxxxxx",
            "errorType": "UNKNOWN"
        }
    }
],
"data": null

}

Founded! Still having my calls in BETA Verison.
After migrating to Version 1 endpoint and syntax, all went OK!
